# LinkedHashMap with tags to fetch messages by specific criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, tags, linkedhashmap

I don't know if it's possible.. i never saw this on any language but hopefully someone wrote it and I missed it! :)

I'm writing a NodeJS 7.2.1 project.

is there some sort of a LinkedHashMap with tags? :)

i have 5 servers that sends messages to one master server. i need it to store the messages in the order that it received it, but I also want to easily delete or query messages based on the server id. that's the most important feature! if there are really tags support and I can also filter by type of messages and other criterias that would be awesome!

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for now i found sqlite the most suitable solution, if anyone have any ideas i'd love to hear it :)